# CMake не видит компилятор в связки с conan

Tags: docker, cmake, devops, gitlab-ci, conan

Я запускаю докер контейнер на gitlab CI:

```
- docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
- docker buildx create --use
- docker buildx build --no-cache -t $CI_REGISTRY/${IMAGE_NAME}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push .
```

Вот сам Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]

ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing 
RUN apt install -y \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    libusb-1.0-0-dev \
    wget \
    unzip \
    build-essential \
    checkinstall \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libtool-bin \
    libplist-dev \
    libusbmuxd-dev \
    usbmuxd \
    libssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    sudo \
    curl \
    vim \
    cmake \
    cython3 \
    libboost-all-dev\
    libgnutls28-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libzip-dev\
    libgcrypt-dev \
    libp11-kit-dev\
    python-dev\
    android-tools-adb \
    libimobiledevice-dev \
    fuse \
    libimobiledevice6 \
    libimobiledevice-utils

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade conan==2.0.7

RUN conan profile detect

COPY profile_arm32 /root/.conan2/profiles/

COPY conanfile.py .

RUN mkdir build_conan_linux
RUN conan install . -of=build_conan_linux --build=missing --profile:build profile_arm32 --profile:host profile_arm32
```

Когда я выполняю строку conan install, то я получаю эту ошибку

*Recipe 'bzip2/1.0.8' cannot build its binary
It is possible that this recipe is not Conan 2.0 ready
If the recipe comes from ConanCenter check: https://conan.io/cci-v2.html
If it is your recipe, check if it is updated to 2.0*

```
ERROR: bzip2/1.0.8: Error in build() method, line 63
cmake.configure(build_script_folder=os.path.join(self.source_folder, os.pardir))
ConanException: Error 1 while executing
```

Эта ошибка следует из этой:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
/root/.conan2/p/b/base6ccce83dbb50d0/b/src
Looking for getopt.h
Looking for getopt.h - found
```

Эта проблема возникает только в образе arm. Если создавать для x86 / x64, то все будет билдиться нормально. Нет разницы какие conan зависимости используются. Я, например, использую эти:

```
from conan import ConanFile

class LibMobileDevice(ConanFile):
    name = "LibMobileDevice"
    version = "1.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "arch", "build_type"
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("libiconv/1.17")
        self.requires("libzip/1.8.0")
        self.requires("libxml2/2.10.3")
        self.requires("boost/1.80.0")
        self.requires("libcurl/7.79.1")
```

В чем может быть проблема? Какие шаги можно предпринять для решения этой проблемы? Компилятор - gcc, пытался задать пути через **ENV CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc**, но не помогло

conan profile:

```
[settings]
arch=armv7
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=11.2
compiler.exception=seh
compiler.threads=posix
os=Linux
build_type=Release
[options]
libcurl/*:with_openssl=True
libcurl/*:with_unix_sockets=False
pkgconf/*:shared=True
zlib/*:shared=True
xz_utils/*:shared=True
boost/*:without_fiber=True
boost/*:without_stacktrace=True
[buildenv]
CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
```

Почему он не находит мой компилятор? Это особенности arm?